# Laravel 5: Set or get date format in DB

Tags: php, laravel, date, laravel-5, php-carbon

I'm having troubles understand how Laravel works with dates and Carbon. I have a model which has a special field called published_at (It's da DATE field). I want laravel to convert that field using carbon when I save an instance the object.

This is my model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Addon extends Model
{

// ...

protected $dates = [

    'published_at'
];

// ....

/**
 * Set the published_at date format
 *
 * @param $date
 * @return string
 */
public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date)
{
    $this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);
}

// ....
}
```

So, to my understanding, the published_at field should now be saved as an instance of carbon using d/m/Y format. However it gets saved as mm-dd-yyyy in the DB.

In the end, I don't care how it's saved to the DB, so that's why I thought to create a `getPublishedAtAttribute` and retrieve it with the format I want. That didn't work either.

All I want is Laravel to format it d/m/Y. Without me having to do something like `{{ $addon->published_at->format('d/m/Y') }}` whenever I show it.

Btw: I'd like the same thing for `created_at` and `updated_at`. Any ideas what I did wrong?

Laravel version: 5.3.31

Comment: MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. 
You could make a getter in the model that returns the value formatted as you would like it to display in the views.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you don't mess around with the date formats like that, instead create an accessor like this..

```
public function getFormattedPublishedAtAttribute() {
    return $this->published_at->format('d/m/Y');
}
```

This way, you can use the default date and also get the formatted date separately using..

```
$model->formattedPublishedAt;
```

Comment: Should this work?

    public function getPublishedAtAttribute($date)
    {
        return $date->format('d/m/Y');
    }

Because for me, I get `Call to a member function format() on string`

Comment: When you do `$model->published_at` Laravel will check if there is a `getPublishedAtAttribute()` method and if so, pass it the value. But since we're using a different name, Laravel won't know which attribute we want, that's why we have to specify it with `return $this->published_at->format()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the format date in the Carbon instruction:

```
$this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright so after some further digging, I did this:

```
public function getPublishedAtAttribute($date)
{
    $date = new Carbon($date);
    return $date->format('d/m/Y');
}
```

And this is working. However I don't understand why I have to do `$date = new Carbon($date);` in order for it to function. If I leave it out I get `Call to a member function format() on string`. (tried with `published_at`, `created_at` and `updated_at`, all the same).

But since `published_at` is in my `$dates = [];` array, shouldn't it be treated like a carbon instance automatically? Even more so with `created_at` and `updated_at`?

But as far as I can see, it's not. If I `dd($addon->created_at);` it's just a string, not a carbon instance (if I leave out the `$date = new Carbon($date);`).

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. It is an carbon instance. Still it doesn't make sense to me why I have to new up a carbon instance in the accessor.

Comment: You do not need to create a Carbon instance. Dates in Laravel for `created_at` and `updated_at` are Carbon instances by default. If you are using soft deletes, you realised that you will need to create a `protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];` This is to create a Carbon instance for `deleted_at`.